# iOS device model incremental number

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I'm doing a video call app and I want to optimize it by adjust video frame size based on device model. Obviously with higher model, I want a bigger video frame size and vice versa.

I know that we have device hardware string (iPhone4,1 iPhone5,1 ...) and now with new iPhone8, 8+ and iPhoneX it has string iPhone10,1 iPhone 10,2 .. iPhone10,6  . But we have to trim this string and besides we also have iPad, iPod.

Is there any incremental number for each iOS device model that we know the larger it is, the newer device model it was.

Comment: Show your code, what you've tried since now.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of relying on device model, it will be better to write media queries css which can enable you to write screen size based style rules for the frame.

Please check http://stephen.io/mediaqueries/ for details on rules for iPhone/iPad.

Comment: This is not what I want. I just want to determine which video frame size I should use. 
For example, with old iPhone like iPhone 5s and older, use 360x480. With newer model like iPhone 6 and newer, use 480x640.
Ofcourse I can trim the device hardware string to get the number and write if/else code to check for iPhone, iPad, iPod
But I'm not sure if newer iPhone model will continue this rule